# Connection of Nammalwar's work with Sanskrit Vedas

Tags: vedas, sri-vaishnava, alwar, tamil

Nammalwar was one of the [Alwars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars) (Tamil:ஆழ்வார், Hindi: आलवार), a group of 12 ancient Tamil saints known for their poetry of 4000 verses in praise of Vishnu and preaching [Sharanagati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saranagati). These 4000 verses were later compiled by Natha Muni as [Nalayira Divya Prabandham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naalayira_Divya_Prabhandham) which is considered alike or equivalent to Sanskrit Vedas (known as Dravida Veda) in Sri Vaishnava Sampradaya.

Nammalwar is considered the greatest among 12 Alwars, he has contributed more than 1100+ verses in Nalayira Divya Prabandham. His four works are considered the essence of (or corresponds to) each of four Vedas in as follows:

1. Thiruvaimozhi (தாந்திருவாய்மொழி) : 1102 verses - Sama Veda
2. Thiruviruttam (திருவிருத்தம்) : 100 verses - Rig Veda
3. Peria Thiruvanthadi (பெரிய திருவந்தாதி) : 87 verses - Atharva Veda
4. Thiruvasiriyam (திருவாசிரியம்) :7 verses - Yajur Veda

Now, what I want to know is:

- Does this connection mean these works are based on Sanskrit Vedas or contains the similar/alike preaching to that of corresponding Vedas?
- How is the connection of these works with Sanskrit Veda recognised or established?

Comment: "Does this connection mean...." It contains similar/alike preaching as that of corresponding Vedas. 

"How is the connection........" Take for Example Triuvaimozhi it is so great that atleast 1,80,000 verses(more that mahabharata) of commentaries are written for it and still there is scope of new commentary. Since bhagwan himself said in BG 10.22 "I am vedas amongst samaveda" so to as a beautiful analogy Tiruvaimozhi it is equated with Samaveda.

Comment: yes. they are called Tamil Veda (தமிழ் மறை). several verses from vedas have literal 'translations' e.g. from purusha suktam. the commentaries of acharyas establish the connections. just as the 4 vedas are represented in above, the 6 vedangas are also represented in another azhwar's verses.

Answer (score 1):

Nammalwar's Thiruvaymozhi is equal to Veda in that it too is sruthi. It is considered superior to Veda since it points out the Supreme Being directly and lucidly. This is stated in Acharya Hrudayam, a Manipravalam work written by Azhagiya Manavala Perumal Nayanar.

The Vedas, however, are intended for people of all varieties of temperaments and traits, so kainkaryam to Him is only one small portion of the Vedas and is interwoven in and around other subjects.

From beginning to end, the Nalayiram speaks only of the Supreme Being and Boundless Kindness towards all. Consequently, Nayanar says that, in this way, it is superior to Vedas

Comment: Welcome. You can do it once You should not post comments as answers. Once you have earned 50 reputation, you will be able to comment directly.  [See How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [When and how are my answers deleted?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Addd some sources in your answer. So that your answer will be retained otherwise it might get deleted. Have a good time around here. :)