# How do Thenkalais support the notion that the Divya Prabandhams are equivalent to the Sanskrit Vedas?

Tags: vedas, sri-vaishnava

The Purva Mimamsa school gives arguments to prove that the Vedas are the foremost authority. Can the same be given for the 4000 Divya Prabandhams?

Comment: This is not just Thenkalai belief, even Vadakalais also believe the same.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan I thought Vadakalais don't believe they are equivalent?

Comment: In Prabandha saram, Swami VedantAcharya proudly proclaims that he is 'Tamizh mariyOn' i.e., follower of Tamil Vedas a.k.a Divya Prabhandhams.

Comment: Why to go as per mimamsa views ?

Comment: @Ikshvaku All Sri Vaishnavas consider the Naalayira Divya Prabandham to be Dravida Veda.  Nathamuni says in his invocatory verse in the beginning of the Thiruvaimozhi, "Namamyaham Dravida Veda Sagaram".  In any case, I vaguely remember seeing Sri Vaishnava works that discuss the Pramanya (authoritativeness) of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham, not in a first-principles way like how the authority of the Vedas is demonstrated, but just demonstrating that the message of the Alwars' poems is in complete agreement with what Vedas say.

Comment: @Ikshvaku In any case, it is true that Thenkalais put slightly more emphasis on the Alwars' poem  than Vadakalais do, but Thenkalais and Vadakalais are in complete agreement on the status of the Naalayira Divya Prabandham.  None of the Ashtadasa Bheda or 18 differences between Thenkalais and Vadakalais are actually about the Alwars' poems.  But some of them arise out of how to interpret Alwars' poems.

Comment: Related: [Connection of Nammalwar's work with Sanskrit Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17967/277).